# Need to solve tailwind positioning of text

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am having trouble setting the correct text position with Tailwind CSS classes.  I want the text to be centered across the middle of two different background colors.

This is the desired design:
[image: desired design]

This is what I get with my code:
[image: current design]

```
<div class="bg-white font-circularstd -mt-12 z-0">
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <div class="bg-orange-bgbody2 w-720 h-800">
    <h2 class="text-center text-md3 pt-139">Promoted Jobs</h2>
    <p class="text-center text-md2 pt-16">
      These opportunities are shown on every page of our site and shared
      daily on our Twitter account.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I did a research but couldn't find any information about positioning a text in the middle of 2 background colors.

Comment: You still have to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured that out. I needed to use only one div and use l=**linear-gradient**

First we need to go to **tailwind.config.js** and add following code:

```
theme: {
extend: {
   backgroundImage: {
    'split-colors': "linear-gradient(90deg, #FFEED9 50% , white 50%);"
  }
 }
```